# UIWebView rotate content

Tags: ios, uiwebview

When autorotating to Landscape mode the size of my `UIWebView` changes perfectly, only the content remains in Portrait mode.

How do I let the `UIWebView` display the content in Landscape mode as well?

*Edit*
There is really nothing special about the code;

I connect the UIWebView in the Nib file and in the UIViewController I do;

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
```

and

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

The `UIWebView` changes size correctly, but the content doesn't rotate.

Comment: What is loading in your UIWebView?

Comment: When you say "content in Landscape" do you mean you want the content to appear sideways (vertical on the horizontal iphone) instead of always upright?

Comment: @Brandon, anything and everyting.

Comment: @MattLeff, Yes thats exactly what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method has been overridden to return a YES, hence supporting all orientations for the UIWebView. And load the webview using a UIViewController

Comment: could you post the relevant code please? i have no such issues when I replicate the same

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer if the original poster seems to indicate that he's already doing it and it doesn't work.  No disrespect to the answer--it's a perfectly fine answer--I just don't understand why it's accepted if it didn't solve the user's problem.  Or did it and that fact just isn't mentioned in the comment thread?

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried setting the UIViewController's view to the UIWebView?

```
[self setView:webView];
```

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 6 upwards, this no longer applies because shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation has been depreciated [see here for a solution](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/where-did-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-go-in-ios-6)

**Tozar's** solution worked best for me.

In my ViewController's *ViewDidLoad* I added **self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;**

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `autoresizesSubviews = YES` for all of the parent views of your `UIWebView`.

You should also try simply setting a breakpoint in your `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method to make sure it is actually being called. It will give you a better idea of what is going wrong in your code.